# adding advanced functionality to flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently developing a flutter app, which contain 3 tabs, 1 for dashboard, for displaying activity, for setings,and one for profile.

in activity section I am hitting the API and displaying its result in cards , example, once clicking activity button API returns a JSON of some 10 data, so there are 10 cards gets created inside activity tab, each card once clicke internally calls the another api and display the result which consist of some entries like 5 header fields and corresponding its entries.

till here I am not facing any issue.

what I am trying to do is in dashboard section I want to create a container which show the last 3 clicked cards in the activity tab.

i.e a user logged in and he clicked on the activity inside that he clicked on any of the cards present and viewed its contents, I want to display those cards in my container inside dashboard, so he can view the last accessed cards in the dashboard itself  to have the quick access, otherwise he has to go to activity section all time and to search for those cards.

can u help me with the approach so how can I keep track of the cards he accessed, and how to show those inside the dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of functionality you will need one list of cards which is accessible from activity and dashboard tab,

Then if user clicks on any card you can add that card object to your local list of cards.

And show that list of cards in dashboard.

This approach will work on local store only,

And if user left app the list will be null.

If you have any other specific situation, please elaborate the question,

I may further help you in that case.